# crop pdf by windows dimensions not by margins sizes

Tags: windows, pdf-editor

On MacOS' Preview.app, you can define the crop area of a PDF by a coordinate and width/height. I very often use this feature to get cropped images of a precise size and integrate them at scale on a report.

However, all Windows PDF tools I've tested so far define the crop area by margin control (top, bottom, left, right). This forces me to do math to get my crop area size right.

Is there any windows software that can define a crop area by coordinate +width/height?

pictures below to show what I mean:

[image]

[image: adobe acrobat pro on Windows]